# Advice is best taken in open fields

Tags: torah-study

This quote is from Rabbi Nachman [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaMiddot%2C_Advice.8?ven=The_aleph_bet_book,_translated_by_Moshe_Mykoff._New_York:_Breslov_Research_Institute,_1986&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%A6%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%94%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A1%D6%BB%D7%92%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA%D6%B5%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A9%D6%BC%D7%82%D6%B8%D7%93%D6%B6%D7%94)

הָעֵצָה הִיא מְסֻגֶּלֶת יוֹתֵר בַּשָּׂדֶה
Counsel is best taken in open fields.

What exactly does this mean?
Can it be understood as "Advice is best taken with an open mind"?

Comment: It is best to hear counsel in the presence of others, who may have other ideas to offer?

Answer (score 6):

This idea is found in [Gemara Brachos](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.8b.13?lang=bi), and is learned from Yaakov: "“And Yaakov sent and he called Rachel and Leah to the field to his flock." The reason for this, as explained by Rashi, is captured in the saying "the walls have ears". This means that even in places that seem private, others may overhear your conversation. In a field, it's easier to tell if anyone is listening, so it's a more secure place for private talks.

Comment: It also pops up a few times in various midrashim

Answer (score -1):

Could also mean Hitbodedut....

Comment: Please add in any sources to support your answer.